# ListItem should change bg color, color of text and images on it while pressed

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, highlight, listitem

I have a ListView, where each item has a custom LinearLayout with a bg image, a textView and 2 imageViews.
Now I need that while the user is touching the item, all of those switch to the "pressed" state:

- the bg image of the LiearLayout must be replaced with another one
- the TextView should change textColor
- both ImageViews in the item should switch to alternative images

Normally such stuff would be done using an xml resource with selector inside, e.g. the LinearLayout would use a drawable with selector inside for background, the TextView a drawable with selector and colors for textColor, and ImageViews use selector with images inside for src.

The problem is that the pressed state is only detected by the LinearLayout and not by the child views (?), so only the background image changes.

I've tried implementing this using OnTouchListener, but then comes the problem that I can't securely get access to Views inside the list item.

I tried caching the view which I return in getView() of the list item to then later change the images and text color. This works usually, but e.g. if one of the list items opens another activity, then the view somehow gets lost and the highlighted state stays indefinitely. I've tried debugging and it works correctly if I step thru with the debugger.

Also, reusing the cachedView seems to bring no good and messes things up completely, so I'm just inflating a new view for the list item each time (this must be inefficient).

Just in case, here is the code of the custom list item item i'm using for the custom list adapter:

```
public class MyListItem extends AbstractListItem
{
    private int iconResource, iconHighlightedResource;
    private int textResource;
    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
    private LinearLayout currentView;

    private ImageView imgIcon;
    private TextView txtText;
    private ImageView imgArrow;
    private boolean bIsHighlighted;

    public MyListItem(int iconResource, int iconHighlightedResource, int textResource, View.OnClickListener onClickListener)
    {
        this.iconResource = iconResource;
        this.iconHighlightedResource = iconHighlightedResource;
        this.textResource = textResource;
        this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    }

    public View getView(View cachedView)
    {
        this.currentView = buildView();
        populateView();
        update();
        return this.currentView;
    }

    private LinearLayout buildView()
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)App.get().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        return (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_menu_item, null);
    }
    private void populateView()
    {
        this.imgIcon = (ImageView)this.currentView.findViewById(R.id.img_menu_item_icon);
        this.txtText = (TextView)this.currentView.findViewById(R.id.txt_menu_item_text);
        this.txtText.setText(this.textResource);
        this.txtText.setTypeface(App.fontCommon);
        this.imgArrow = (ImageView)this.currentView.findViewById(R.id.img_menu_item_arrow);
        this.currentView.setOnClickListener(this.onClickListener);
        this.currentView.setOnTouchListener(this.highlighter);
    }

    private View.OnTouchListener highlighter = new View.OnTouchListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
        {
            int nAction = event.getAction();
            int nActionCode = nAction & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
            switch (nActionCode)
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    bIsHighlighted = true;
                    update();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    bIsHighlighted = false;
                    update();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    private void update()
    {
        if (this.bIsHighlighted)
        {
            updateForHighlightedState();
        }
        else
        {
            updateForNormalState();
        }
    }

    private void updateForHighlightedState()
    {
        Resources r = App.get().getResources();
        this.currentView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_beveled_m_call_to_action_taking_input);
        this.imgIcon.setImageResource(this.iconHighlightedResource);
        this.txtText.setTextColor(r.getColor(R.color.white));
        this.imgArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow_highlighted);
    }
    private void updateForNormalState()
    {
        Resources r = App.get().getResources();
        this.currentView.setBackgroundColor(r.getColor(R.color.white));
        this.imgIcon.setImageResource(this.iconResource);
        this.txtText.setTextColor(r.getColor(R.color.text_dark));
        this.imgArrow.setImageResource(R.drawable.arrow);
    }
}
```

Here is the layout file (xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_menu_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/info" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_menu_item_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:text="Menu item"
        android:textColor="@color/text_dark"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_menu_item_arrow"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After lots of experimenting finally this worked:
Every child view inside the list item layout must have `android:duplicateParentState="true"`.
Then all of them can just use selector drawables. No extra effort inside the code is required.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/my_item_bg"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_menu_item_icon"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/selector_info"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_menu_item_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:text="Menu item"
        android:textColor="@drawable/selector_color_my_button_text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/selector_arrow"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i see you changed the background of the TextView from a color to a drawable... so whats the content of selector_color_my_button_text?

Comment: You saved my time. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You should create custom drawable selectors, and set them as the background to your listview element.

Step#1, create another layout (named: layout_selected for this example), with the appropriate background color for your pressed state (like the layout file you supplied, but with the background attribute of the linear set to another color).

Then you will define a drawable selector, which will be placed in your drawable folder), defining which background should be use in which instance.  This will look something like this:

```
<!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_normal" android:state_focused="true"/>
<!-- default -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/layout_normal"/>
```

Finally, to use this in your list, when you set the layout for your adapter, set it to the selector we just created, instead of your standard layout.

Maybe a little hard to explain, but you want to use 'Drawable Selectors' to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but this will only work for the background and won't change the views which are attached to the list view. Or have I understood you incorrectly?

Comment: You can specify whatever view you would like in the different layouts.  You can control whatever you would like by supplying an alternate layout.  You have in fact understood me incorrectly, as you can control any element of your UI by providing appropriate values in your alternate layouts.  I am sure this is your answer.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to add ViewHolder pattern for listview. This will optimize your listview drawing & creating UI.

Also in that we can use setTag to save instance of row. In that you can handle touch event.

Comment: Good idea to use the ViewHolder, but this doesn't solve the problem he is asking about.

Comment: Indeed, just tried, and the problem is still the same: the OnTouchListener can't access a TextView inside the list item because neither the View object or the ViewHolder object can be saved. Instead, you can only receive them inside getView() method

Comment: ok then use an observer design pattern by creating one interface that interface should be implemented by each UI row. & from OnTouchListener  of Listview call the that method.